# Why github 'commmits on date' and committed date is different?

Tags: git, github

[github contribution log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPKjR.png)

Hello, I recently changed all of the authors and email in my contribution logs with git rebase.
However, after I doing it and I pushed it to my repository, all of my contribution logs looks like that.

What I want to know is why the commits on date and committed date is different.

Is there any way to make the same commited date and commits on date?

Comment: Were these commits merged in from another branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change the author dates**

It seems that GitHub shows the `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` on the timeline and `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` on individual commits.

If so, the possible remedy is to use:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter 'GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$GIT_COMMITTER_DATE'
```